# CSS ul li if remove 1 make others bigger

Tags: css

The height of my `ul` is 500px. How can I make the `li` height dynamic to the number of `li` there are? For example, if I have 5 `li`, then the height would be 20%, if 4 `li`, then it changes to 25%.

Here is what I tried, but if I remove one element from "developer mode", the height doesn't change.

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li{
    width:100px;
    height:25%;
    background:red;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crcb8/

[image]

Comment: I don't think CSS can do this, you might have to use JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little jquery will get you what you need, and is supported by majority of browsers and mobile devices

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var x = $('li').siblings().length;
     var y = 100/x;
     $('li').css('height', y + '%');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll either have to use JavaScript or rely on the flexible box model (flexbox), which isn't supported by all browsers:

```
ul {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    flex-flow: column;

    list-style: none;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    width:100px;
    height:25%;
    background:red;
    border:1px solid black;

    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/crcb8/4/**

Comment: It's such a shame that the browser support is bad, because it's so cool.

Answer (score 0):

As blender said, this is not cross browserly(?) possible with css.

The best solution would be a tiny bit of javascript code that can calculate the height for you, like this demo for example

```
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('#box li'), // Get the boxes
    size  = 100 / boxes.length; // Calculate the percentage 
for( var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++ ) {
    boxes[i].style.height = size + '%'; // Set the height
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/crcb8/6/**

Answer (score 0):

No idea about CSS. but maybe this jQuery code will be useful for you:

jsfiddle.net/crcb8/8/

NOTICE this is my first jQuery code I made. Also you need care about border and padding to get required height.